# google oauth2 get token javascript post request

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I saw some questions and answers about this but couldn't understand what to do.
I get this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`
As I saw from previous posts, this is because I can't make an HTTP POST request to another server. I saw some things about using jsonp but couldn't understand how..
This is the function I use to send the request:

```
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
var payload = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: authResult['code'],
    client_id: clientID,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: '',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
};

$.post(url, {
    form: payload
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your app ?

> ### Obtaining OAuth Keys :
>
> - Visit Google Cloud Console
> - Click CREATE PROJECT button
> - Enter Project Name, then click CREATE
> - Then select APIs & auth from the sidebar and click on Credentials tab
>
>   - Click CREATE NEW CLIENT ID button
>   - Application Type: Web Application
>   - **Authorized Javascript origins: http://localhost:63342**
>   - **Authorized redirect URI: http://localhost:63342/...**

*Note: Make sure you have turned on the APIs you need.*

The important part is : **Authorized Javascript origins: http://localhost:63342**, you need to autorize your website domain to access the API.

The endpoint is bad use `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token` [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    data: {
        code :"",
        client_id : "",
        client_secret : "",
        redirect_uri : "",
        grant_type : "authorization_code"
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: function(e){console.log(e)}
});
```

Comment: added the domains you told me. Also added the API's you said.
The error is still there

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait 4/5 minutes.

Comment: Then the issue is in the Ajax call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83882/discussion-between-javi-dorfsman-and-thom-x).